# Clean HTML documentation template for Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I use Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems for reverse-engineering URL class diagrams from my source code, and want to take this a step further by using the software to generate HTML API documentation of my code.

However I find the markup generated by Enterprise Architect to be full of Javascript, and I think I may have even spotted some VB Script in there.  Want I want is a clean HTML-only template that I can use to produce simple markup that will work fine in all browsers.

I have tried to manually create this template using the template editor in Enterprise Architect 8, but find this cumbersome.

Does anyone know of an existing template I can use, or an easier way to generate a template without using the built in template editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use JavaScript, you can turn it on by allowing XMLHTTPRequest in your browser. It works well in Firefox, Opera and IE.
EA HTML Template doesn't give much possibilities but you can modify everything thanks to JavaScript.

Another way is to export all diagrams as png or other image file and then manually create a static web page.

Comment: I've given up on using EA for auto-generated API docs, and as you suggested I just manually import the png files from EA into my HTML which is less than ideal.